# database on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

friend i want that , i have xib and that xib name is mapper ok and this xib i have one tab bar button and in this tabbar i give link of web server page which direct open the user registration from and user can fill there from easy ok on the registration from have submit button if user submit there data then after i have fast retrive there data from server database which user fill on registration from and that i have get username and password bec after the registration from complete then user come on login pagexib in this xib i have give a
authority to user please enter ur username and password if user enter there username and password he should chek from database it this username have or not and this all information i have to store from server to local database after this hapen then i have to match username and password from local database which i am sqlitedatabase it this possbel friend if yes then give me some information about yhis type of database save and retrive in iphone and please give me some small code of this releted this project

Comment: Abhishek, I understand that English probably isn't your first language, but the way you've written this makes it hard for people to read and access, and therefore hard for people to help. I was going to edit it for you, but I think you'd be better served doing it yourself. Punctuation, complete sentences, and writing that's not just capturing the words that come out of your mouth as you talk--all of these will go a long way toward getting actual help for your problem.

Comment: while that is certainly true, I think I gave him the solution he needs ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the NSUserDefaults object in the apple docs
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It's as simple as this

```
-(void)saveCustomObject:(MyCustomObject*)obj
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];


    [defaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"myEncodedObjectKey"];
}

-(MyCustomObject*)loadCustomObjectWithKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSUserDefaults defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [defaults objectForKey: key];
    MyCustomObject* obj = (MyCustomObject*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject];
    return obj;
}
```